# IBM Globalization (service for Bluemix)

Tags: translation, ibm-cloud, globalization-pipeline

I am using Bluemix. I used to be able to locate the Globalization service, but now I can't find it. Where is it?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, as an experimental service, the **IBM Globalization** service doesn't show up in the Bluemix [catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?ace_base=true/#/store/) at all if you aren't logged in. So, to view the service in the catalog:

1. log in
2. go to the [Catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?ace_base=true/#/store/)
3. scroll all the way to the bottom and you will see a beaker and a link to [Bluemix labs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?ace_base=true/#/store/&labs=true) with the title "Looking for something more? Click this..
4. You should now see **IBM Globalization** and other experimental services in the **Bluemix labs** page.

If you are binding or adding the service, the steps are similar:

1. click on "+ ADD A SERVICE OR API"
2. scroll all the way to the bottom and you will see a beaker and a link to [Bluemix labs](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/?ace_base=true/#/store/&labs=true) with the title "Looking for something more? Click this..
3. You should now see **IBM Globalization** and other experimental services in the **Bluemix labs** page.

*Note*, 
 If you just want to see the service info and read the docs, this [direct link](https://ibm.biz/BluemixGlobalization) will get you there.